# ConcurrentDictionary doesn't seem to mark elements for GC when they are removed

Tags: c#, collections, concurrency, .net-4.0, garbage-collection

I was surprised to find that my app memory footprint kept growing - the longer it run, the more memory it consumed. So with some magic of `windbg` I pinpointed a problem to my little LRU cache based on `ConcurrentDictionary`. The CD has bunch of benefits that were very cool for me (one of which is that its data never ends up in LOH). `TryAdd` and `TryRemove` are two methods used to add and evict items. `!gcroot` of some older element lead me back to my cache. Some investigation with ILSpy led me to this conclusion:

`TryRemove` does *not* really remove an element. All it does is changing linked list pointers to skip never assigning the value of an array element to `null`. This prevent GC from collecting old evicted objects.

Really? Is that a known problem? If so is my only option is `TryUpdate(key, null)` and then `TryRemove(key)`? If so then I have to have locking around `ConcurrentDictionary` access which is oxymoronic.

Here is ILSpy dump:

```
// System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>
private bool TryRemoveInternal(TKey key, out TValue value, bool matchValue, TValue oldValue)
{
    while (true)
    {
        ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Tables tables = this.m_tables;
        int num;
        int num2;
        this.GetBucketAndLockNo(this.m_comparer.GetHashCode(key), out num, out num2, tables.m_buckets.Length, tables.m_locks.Length);
        lock (tables.m_locks[num2])
        {
            if (tables != this.m_tables)
            {
                continue;
            }
            ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Node node = null;
            ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Node node2 = tables.m_buckets[num];
            while (node2 != null)
            {
                if (this.m_comparer.Equals(node2.m_key, key))
                {
                    bool result;
                    if (matchValue && !EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default.Equals(oldValue, node2.m_value))
                    {
                        value = default(TValue);
                        result = false;
                        return result;
                    }
                    if (node == null)
                    {
                        Volatile.Write<ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Node>(ref tables.m_buckets[num], node2.m_next);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        node.m_next = node2.m_next;
                    }
                    value = node2.m_value;
                    tables.m_countPerLock[num2]--;
                    result = true;
                    return result;
                }
                else
                {
                    node = node2;
                    node2 = node2.m_next;
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    value = default(TValue);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What version(s) ? I remember an issue like this with the first ConcurrentQueue (Fx4)

Comment: And take a look at TryGet, is that a typo?

Comment: Any news with this - I have the same issue...